# Does R provide anything cleaner than tryCatch() to safely make SQL queries?

Tags: sql, r, try-catch

I am making SQL queries, using `tryCatch()` to prevent R from silently using up all the slots for database connections.  It looks like this:

```
sql <- "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE zipcode=10202"
con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), user='user', password='pswd',
                 dbname='contacts',host='dbserv')
tryCatch( {
    rs <- dbSendQuery(con, statement=sql)                              
    fp <- fetch(rs,n=-1) # Fetch all
    dbClearResult(rs)
    fp},
  finally=dbDisconnect(con))
fp
```

Does R provide anything cleaner for the purpose?  I'm thinking of how `readLines()` works with a string argument to make sure no file connection is left open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try [on.exit](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/on.exit.html), something like the following:

```
    foo <- function() {

      con <- dbConnect(
        PostgreSQL(),
        user=config$db.user,
        password=config$db.password,
        dbname=config$db.name,
        host=config$db.host
      )

      on.exit({
        dbDisconnect(con)
      })

      ## ... do something w/ connection

    }
```

When the function `foo` is about to return (or exit due to an exception), the expression passed to `on.exit` will be evaluated.

Comment: I like that a lot -- I did not know about `on.exit`.  One really nice aspect to it is that one can use the `add=TRUE` argument after each time a file or database connection object is opened.